# back-propagation derivatives

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

In the 10th video of week3 of Ng course on Deep Neural Networks in coursera, there is a slide that i attached. Why he used elementwise product (vs normal matrix product) in this slide? Is it only for match-up of matrices for other products?[image: slide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a youtube video where I go through some backprop at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppJwiv1qtlE&t=12s

Basically you chain-rule everything. And $g$ is the activation function, which is per-element.

In detail, the above net is two layers with mse loss. So, the forward direction would be something like, in code:

```
z1 = g(W1 @ x + b1)
z2 = g(W2 @ z1 + b2)
loss = MSELoss(z2, y)
```

... where:

- `g` is an activation function, like `tanh`, or `sigmoid`, or `ReLU`
- `x` is the input to the network
- `z` is the output of each layer, after activation
- `W` is weight matrix of a layer, and
- `b` is bias of a layer

Mathematically, this is:

$$
\def\z{\mathbf{z}}
\def\W{\mathbf{W}}
\def\b{\mathbf{b}}
\def\y{\mathbf{y}}
\def\x{\mathbf{x}}
\z_1 = g(\W_1 \x + \b_1) \\
\z_2 = g(\W_2 \z_1 + \b_2) \\
\mathcal{L} = \text{MSELoss}(\z_2, \y)
$$

When we chain-rule this, we can do bit by bit. So, we can take the second layer output $\z_2$, and derive with respect to the input $\z_1$:

$$
\frac{\partial \z_2}{\partial \z_1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \z_1} (g(\W_2\z_1 + \b_2))
$$

Let's substitute $h(\z_1) = \W_2 \z_1 + \b_2$, so we have:

$$
\frac{\partial \z_2}{\partial \z_1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \z_1} (g(h(\z_1))
$$

By chain rule this is:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \z_1} (g(h(\z_1)) =
\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial \z_1}
$$

... which doesnt itself involve any matrix multiplication. The partial derivative $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \z_1}$ will involve differentiating matrices, but the two partial derivatives themselves are simply multiplied together.